How to Create Nested Facets in Altair with Consistent Scale Across Rows?
I'm working on a data visualization project in Python using Altair, and I'm struggling with creating nested facets with consistent scales across all rows. I want to create a plot that facets on one variable and sub-facets on another, but I need all rows to share the same scale for better comparability.
Problem Description
I have a DataFrame called movies with the following structure:
genre   studio  voteavg_runtime_ratio   revenue_runtime_ratio
Action  Studio A    1.2 0.8
Action  Studio B    1.1 0.7
Comedy  Studio A    1.4 0.9
Drama   Studio C    1.3 0.85
... ... ... ...
I want to create nested facets where the main facet is by genre, and within each genre, sub-facets are by studio. Each plot should show the voteavg_runtime_ratio as a bar chart, and I need the x-axes to be consistent across all genre rows.
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
movies = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['Action', 'Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Drama'],
    'studio': ['Studio A', 'Studio B', 'Studio A', 'Studio C', 'Studio D'],
    'voteavg_runtime_ratio': [1.2, 1.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5],
    'revenue_runtime_ratio': [0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.85, 0.9]
})

# Plot
chart = alt.Chart(movies).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('studio:N', title='Studio'),
    y=alt.Y('voteavg_runtime_ratio:Q', title='Vote Average / Runtime Ratio'),
    color='studio:N'
).facet(
    row='genre:N'
).resolve_scale(
    y='shared'
)

chart


Issue
The plot creates facets by genre with sub-facets for studio, but the y-axes are not consistent across the rows, making it hard to compare between genres. Using resolve_scale(y='shared') has not solved the issue.
What I've Tried
Using resolve_scale(y='shared'): This does not seem to affect the alignment or consistency across rows.
Setting scales manually for each facet: Not feasible for a large number of genres and studios.
Desired Outcome
I want all genre rows to share the same y-scale while allowing studio to be the sub-facet in each row. This way, I can compare the voteavg_runtime_ratio across genres with consistent scales.
Is there a way to enforce consistent y-scales across all rows while facetting in Altair?
Any help or insights would be appreciated!

When I run your code (even without y=shared), I get consistent y-axes that goes from 0 - 1.6 for each row. Could you elaborate on how this is differs from what you are expecting? What would you like the y-axis max/min values to be?
